# Android view .pdf file in web view using redirect url by authenticate user name and password

Tags: android, pdf, sharepoint, webview, redirect

I would like to view pdf file from share point server. 
the Url link : https:///sites/iConnect/Lists/FeedList/Attachments/1138/Grasim%20Talent%20Hunt.pdf

it Redirect to the below link:
https://login.microsoftonline.com, once I signed in then the response redirect to pdf file url.

In this institution how I handle and view the pdf file to webview.

I tried this code snip:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(uri);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
  @Override
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
 {
   if(request.getUrl().toString().endsWith(".pdf")) 
   {
     String weburl = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + request.getUrl().toString();
     view.loadUrl(weburl);
    }
    else
    {
       view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
    }

    return true;
 }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
     super.onPageFinished(view, url);
     CommonUtils.dismissDialog();

  }

  @Override
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,String description,String failingUrl) {
//super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
  Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this,"Error"+description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }


 });
```

Please suggest if there is any concepts

Thank you

Rajarajan

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf file to begin with.

Comment: @Rajarajan any solution u got ?

Comment: Any solution? We need to detect pdf contents in the return?

Answer (score 0):

I used onPageStarted instead of shouldOverrideUrlLoading and didn't have any problem.
and i user webView.loadUrl(uri) instead view.loadUrl(weburl). try that.

Answer (score 0):

WebView cannot display a pdf file.You can display the pdf by using below code

```
 if(url.endsWith(".pdf")){

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startActivity(intent);
  }
  else {

       view.loadUrl(url);
  }
```

Comment: You missed the point about the URL redirection. That is the main challenge here. Otherwise we already know we can use an intent as you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with rendering the PDF outside a WebView (e.g., an ImageView), and you're targeting Lollipop (5.0) and up, you can use this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer

I was actually trying it out today and it worked well for me.  What I did was:

- Create a Fragment with an ImageView and then two buttons (one for back one page, one for forward one page)
- Each time the user when forward or back, I created a Bitmap with `Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888)` where w and h are the ImageView's width/height at that point
- I requested the given page number and passed in the new Bitmap where the mBitmap is in the sample code
- I assigned the resulting Bitmap with `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`.

Voila, it worked well.  My code is a prototype, so I'll be refining it, but it rendered dozens of pages well and was relatively quick.  There was a noticeable delay b/w pages, but maybe 1/2 second worth.  If I had pre-loaded / cached pages, the delay would probably be gone.  But, for my prototype, it didn't matter.

I'd highly recommend this approach!

Comment: Thanks, but I think you missed the point about the URL redirection. That is the main challenge here, not how to render a pdf.

Comment: @auspicious99 then I think the question needs to be clarified.  Is it *how to intercept* the URL after the login?  There's technically not a question being asked, so it's hard to fully decipher.  Though, I'd still recommend PdfRenderer as the Google PDF viewer piece *could* be removed by Google at any time leaving the app broken.

Comment: The challenge is to retrieve the PDF file from the server in order to render it. As sending a request to the URL does not simply yield the PDF file in the response, but may redirect to authentication.

Comment: OK, so then it seems to me the solution is along the lines of let the WebView go through the normal authentication flow and if you intercept the URL and get ".pdf", and/or some mime-type header of application/pdf, then save the URL, but stop the flow at that point.